# The Systemd Journald use too much memory and don't respect SystemMaxUse and RuntimeMaxUse?

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, systemd-journald

I found the systemd-journald takes like 1GB+ of memory. After some searching I set the value of SystemMaxUse and RuntimeMaxUse both to 8M in "/etc/systemd/journald.conf". Then restart the journald.

After a while I found that limit doesn't work, check through 'top' and procstat.memory_rss, the systemd-journald still consumes 100+M after a while (Below is the visualization of journald memory catch through procstat.memory_rss). Any idea?

My systemd version is 219.

[image]

Comment: Yep, it does grab a lot of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Both `SystemMaxUse` and `RuntimeMaxUse` control disk space usage not memory usage. `RuntimeMaxUse` does apply to logs on the volatile file system (`/run`) but thats not captured by `procstat.memory_rss` Further neither of those options constrain active log files only archived ones.

If journald really is using a GB I would take a serious look at whats creating all of those logs.

Comment: I agree to jdwolf. Trying to reduce memory space for a system program like journald, instead of figuring out why these logs are growing that crazy is just _lol_.